# csharp string separetion for math operation

Tags: c#, math

I'm doing a calculator with HTML CSS and JQuery with ajax call to a c# code (it's for an exercises given to me to learn a bit ajax and csharp).
I was able to do everything i needed to do, I'm just missing one thing.
The c# code, receive from a file named "Handler.ashx" a string, this string conteins the displalyed operation of the calculator, example: "321/34". now, I should, with c#, find a way to separate the 2 number inside the string and make the operation using the / used as separation. this for every single operation (+, -, /, *)
(I'm not english, so if somethings is not clear please tell me and I'll try to explaine myself better)

Comment: will the expression always be two operands and one operator?

Comment: Please consider posting some code regarding what you want to do.

Comment: Since its for learning, i don't want to spoiler you to much. Try to fiddle around with `string.Split(params char[]? separator)` docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char())

Comment: yea, i made it this way because it would've been too much of a pain creating a calculator with this ajax and c# part that could've had multiple operator and operands because i would've had to also set priorities for the brackets, division ecc...

Comment: And welcome to SO! Please consider reading the [how-to-ask-page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the built-in methods `int IndexOf(char)`

I am using C# 10 (or .Net 6.0), so depending on your version some features might not be available yet, but the logic should be the same

```cs
string test = "147+548";

int plusIndex = test.IndexOf('+');
int minusIndex = test.IndexOf('-');
int mulIndex = test.IndexOf('*');
int divIndex = test.IndexOf('/');

string operation;
float a = 0;
float b = 0;
if (plusIndex != -1)
{
    operation = "PLUS";
    a = float.Parse(test[..plusIndex]);
    b = float.Parse(test[(plusIndex+1)..]);
}
else if (minusIndex != -1)
{
    operation = "MINUS";
    a = float.Parse(test[..minusIndex]);
    b = float.Parse(test[(minusIndex + 1)..]);
}
else if (mulIndex != -1)
{
    operation = "MULTIPLY";
    a = float.Parse(test[..mulIndex]);
    b = float.Parse(test[(mulIndex + 1)..]);
}
else/* if (divIndex == -1)*/
{
    operation = "DIVIDE";
    a = float.Parse(test[..divIndex]);
    b = float.Parse(test[(divIndex + 1)..]);
}

Console.WriteLine($"{a} {operation} {b}");
```

The string[...] I put down are the same as SubString. `[..5]` means from start to index 5 and `[6..]` means from index 6 to the end

Comment: I'm not understanding why the ifs are ...Index != -1. why the "-1"?

Comment: see: [IndexOf(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-indexof(system-string))  "The zero-based index position of value if that string is found, or -1 if it is not."